# Weird issue with Javascript game

Tags: javascript

OK, so I'm new to JS, so am trying to make the basic 'breakout' game. What I'm trying to do is arrange the bricks into a triangle shape (or more accurately, forming a triangle out of the absence of bricks). But when I choose which items in the 2D array I want to equal 0 (no brick), it only allows me choose one. after that, the game simply won't load.

Weirdest thing is, it will only accept the first line in this part. No matter what I change, the second line onwards will cause the game to not load:

```
            bricks[0][10]=0;
            bricks[7][16]=0;
            bricks[7][15]=0;
            bricks[7][14]=0;
            bricks[7][13]=0;
            bricks[7][12]=0;
            bricks[7][11]=0;
            bricks[7][10]=0;
            bricks[7][9]=0;
            bricks[7][8]=0;
            bricks[7][7]=0;
            bricks[7][6]=0;
            bricks[7][5]=0;
            bricks[7][4]=0;
            bricks[7][3]=0;
            bricks[7][17]=0;
            bricks[6][4]=0;
            bricks[6][16]=0;
            bricks[5][15]=0;
            bricks[5][5]=0;
            bricks[4][14]=0;
            bricks[4][6]=0;
            bricks[3][13]=0;
            bricks[3][7]=0;
            bricks[2][8]=0;
            bricks[2][12]=0;
            bricks[1][11]=0;
            bricks[1][9]=0;
```

Also, i know the code is incomplete and flawed as it is. It's not finished and still need a lot of polishing up.
Here's my entire code

```
canvasApp();

function canvasApp(){

var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas")
if (!canvas || !canvas.getContext){
    return;
}
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

if (!ctx) {
        return
}

//Application States

const GAME_STATE_TITLE = 0;
const GAME_STATE_NEW_LEVEL = 1;
const GAME_STATE_GAME_OVER = 2;

var currentGameState = 0;
var currentGameStateFunction = null;
var brickcount;
var bouncecount = 0;

//Initialise Start Screen State
var titleStarted = false;
var gameStarted = false;
var gameOver = false;
var keyPressList = [];
var keys = false //mouse or keys. false = mouse control, vice versa
var difficulty = 0;

 // Declarations for the game

var dx = 6;
var dy = 6;
var x = 150;
var y = 100;
var r = 10;
var WIDTH = 500;
var HEIGHT = 400;
var ballx = 200;
var bally = 200;
var paddlex = WIDTH/1.2;
var paddleh = 10;
var paddlew = 75;
var paddledx = 30
var mouseX;
var bricks;
var NROWS;
var NCOLS;
var BRICKWIDTH;
var BRICKHEIGHT;
var PADDING;
var rowcolours = ["#FF1C0A", "#FFFD0A", "#00A308", "#0008DB", "#EB0093"];
var paddlecolour = "#FF00FF";
var ballcolour = "#00FFFF";
var backcolour = "#0000FF";

function initbricks() {
            NROWS = 9
            NCOLS = 21
            brickcount = NROWS*NCOLS;
            BRICKWIDTH = (WIDTH/NCOLS) - 1;
            BRICKHEIGHT = 10;
            PADDING = 1;

            bricks = new Array(NROWS);
            for (i=0; i < NROWS; i++) {
                bricks[i] = new Array(NCOLS);
            for (j=0; j < NCOLS; j++) {
                bricks[i][j] = 1;
            }
        bricks[0][10]=0;
        bricks[7][16]=0;
        bricks[7][15]=0;
        bricks[7][14]=0;
        bricks[7][13]=0;
        bricks[7][12]=0;
        bricks[7][11]=0;
        bricks[7][10]=0;
        bricks[7][9]=0;
        bricks[7][8]=0;
        bricks[7][7]=0;
        bricks[7][6]=0;
        bricks[7][5]=0;
        bricks[7][4]=0;
        bricks[7][3]=0;
        bricks[7][17]=0;
        bricks[6][4]=0;
        bricks[6][16]=0;
        bricks[5][15]=0;
        bricks[5][5]=0;
        bricks[4][14]=0;
        bricks[4][6]=0;
        bricks[3][13]=0;
        bricks[3][7]=0;
        bricks[2][8]=0;
        bricks[2][12]=0;
        bricks[1][11]=0;
        bricks[1][9]=0;
        }
        }

initbricks();

function switchGameState(newState) {
    currentGameState = newState;
    switch (currentGameState) {
        case GAME_STATE_TITLE:
        currentGameStateFunction = gameStateTitle;
        break;
        case GAME_STATE_NEW_LEVEL:
        currentGameStateFunction = gameStatePlayLevel;
        break;
        case GAME_STATE_GAME_OVER:
        currentGameStateFunction = gameStateGameOver;
        break;
        }
    }

function gameStateTitle(){
    if (titleStarted != true){
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,400);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
        ctx.font = '20px _sans';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
        ctx.fillText ("Breakout!", 200,150);
        ctx.fillText ("Press Space to Play", 170,200);
        if (keys == 0 ) {
            ctx.fillText ("Mouse selected", 180,250);
            ctx.fillText ("Press k to switch to keys", 140,300);
            } else {
            ctx.fillText ("Keys selected", 190,250);
            ctx.fillText ("Press m to switch to mouse", 140,300);
        }
        titleStarted = true;    

    }else{
        if (keyPressList[75] == true){
            keys = 1;
            titleStarted = false;
            gameStateTitle(); // Redraw the title page
            }
        if (keyPressList[77] == true){
            keys = 0;
            titleStarted = false;
            gameStateTitle();
            }
        if (keyPressList[32] == true){
            switchGameState(GAME_STATE_NEW_LEVEL);
            titleStarted = false;
            }
        }
    }


function gameStatePlayLevel(){
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,400);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';


    //  Update the game state and check for game over
        function update() {
        x+=dx
        y+=dy
        if (keys == 0) {
            paddlex = mouseX;
            }else{
            if (keyPressList[37]==true){
            paddlex-=paddledx;
            }
        if (keyPressList[39]==true){
            paddlex+=paddledx;
        }
          }
        //have we hit a brick?
            rowheight = BRICKHEIGHT + PADDING;
            colwidth = BRICKWIDTH + PADDING;
            row = Math.floor(y/rowheight);
            col = Math.floor(x/colwidth);
            //if so, reverse the ball and mark the brick as broken
                 if (y < NROWS * rowheight  && row >= 0 && col >= 0 &&     bricks[row][col] == 1) {
                    dy = -dy;
                    bricks[row][col] = 0;
                    brickcount--;
                    if (brickcount == 0) {
                        switchGameState(GAME_STATE_NEW_LEVEL);
                        difficulty+=1;
                        initbricks();
                        x=250;
                        y=200 + (difficulty*20);
                        brickcount=NROWS*NCOLS;
                        bouncecount=0;
                    }
                }

                    if( x<0 || x>WIDTH) dx=-dx;
            if( y<0 || y>HEIGHT) dy=-dy;
                else if (y + dy > HEIGHT) {
                    if (x > paddlex && x < paddlex + paddlew) {
                        dx = 8 * ((x-(paddlex+paddlew/2))/paddlew);
                        dy = -dy; 
                        bouncecount++;
                    }

        else {
      //game over, so stop the animation
          switchGameState(GAME_STATE_GAME_OVER);
          initbricks();
      }
        }
        }

        function render() {
        ctx.save();
            function circle(x,y,r) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
                ctx.fill();
            }
            function rect(x,y,w,h) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        //draw bricks
            for (i=0; i < NROWS; i++) {
            ctx.fillStyle = rowcolours [i];
                for (j=0; j < NCOLS; j++) {
                    if (bricks[i][j] == 1) {
                    rect((j * (BRICKWIDTH + PADDING)) + PADDING, 
                    (i * (BRICKHEIGHT + PADDING)) + PADDING, BRICKWIDTH,     BRICKHEIGHT);
                    }
                }
            }



        circle(x, y, 10);
        // init_paddle();
        ctx.fillStyle = paddlecolour;
        rect (paddlex, HEIGHT-paddleh, paddlew, paddleh);

        ctx.restore();
        show_result()
        }
        update();
        render();
}

function gameStateGameOver(){
    if (gameOver != true){
        bouncecount=0;
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,400);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
        ctx.font = '20px _sans';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
        ctx.fillText ("Game over", 200,150);
        ctx.fillText ("Press Space to Restart", 160,200);
        ctx.fillText ("You completed " + difficulty + " levels", 160,240);
        difficulty=0;
        gameOver = true;
    }else{
    if (keyPressList[32] == true){
        switchGameState(GAME_STATE_TITLE);
        gameOver = false;
        }
    }
}


function runGame(){
    currentGameStateFunction();
    }

// Key handler

document.onkeydown = function(e){
e= e?e:window.event;
keyPressList[e.keyCode] = true;
}
document.onkeyup = function(e){
e= e?e:window.event;
keyPressList[e.keyCode] = false;
}
function onMouseMove(evt) {
// Event data passes to this function
mouseX = evt.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft - paddlew/2;
// Assign the relative position of the mouse in the canvas to mouseX
mouseY = evt.clientY-canvas.offsetTop;
//Do the same for mouseY
document.title="("+mouseX+","+mouseY+")";
//Put the mouse X and Y in the title for info
paddlex = mouseX;
// Position the paddle
}
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",onMouseMove, false); 

//Application start

switchGameState(GAME_STATE_TITLE);
const FRAME_RATE = 40;
var intervalTime = 1000/FRAME_RATE;
setInterval(runGame, intervalTime);
        function show_result(){
            ctx.fillText ("There are " + brickcount + " bricks", 160,200);
ctx.fillText ("Paddle bounces are " + bouncecount , 160,220);
        }
}
```

Comment: Your nested `for` loops are not closed correctly. The second loop closes after the lines creating the issue. Move the `}` before you set the problem code.

Comment: *"No matter what I change, the second line onwards will cause the game to not load:"* - At which point you should open the browser's dev console and see if there are error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With proper indenting, your code looks like this:

```
        bricks = new Array(NROWS);
        for (i=0; i < NROWS; i++) {
            bricks[i] = new Array(NCOLS);
            for (j=0; j < NCOLS; j++) {
                bricks[i][j] = 1;
            }
            bricks[0][10]=0;
            bricks[7][16]=0;
```

In other words, you're attempting to access `bricks[7]` in the very first iteration when only `bricks[0]` has been created. Properly close the first `for` loop with a `}` before running your list of overrides.

Comment: omg, that's so obvious now you point it out. Thanks! I'm gonna go cry in a corner now

Comment: We've all been there. It's a good reason to get into the habit of indenting consistently, though. Visual feedback does wonders.